# Win server 2008 low disk space email notif

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to set email notification, when facing low disk space. But I need to set this warning on all partitions, not only on C:/.

I scheduled task on event with id 2013, log system, and source server. Will this email notification send mail only when C is low or it will mail a notification when the disk spave on any of the partitions is low?

If not, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is generated for each partition individually.

> By default, Event Viewer may report Event ID 2013 if a partition has 10 percent or less disk space available

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112509/en-us